# How to group by using pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, pivot-table, sql-server-2014

have a table like this:,

```
name  ZK04_COUNT  ZK05_COUNT  ZK04_PRICE  ZK05_PRICE
A     15           0             150.00      0 
A     0            20              0         223.00
B     11           0             75.00       0
B     0            24              0         250.00
```

I'm trying to pivot it to something like this:

```
name  ZK04_COUNT  ZK05_COUNT  ZK04_PRICE  ZK05_PRICE
A         15          20        150.00       223.00
B         11          24         75.00       250.00
```

My code like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT 
       r.name
      ,r.AUART
      , CASE WHEN r.AUART = 'ZK05' THEN count(r.MATNR) ELSE '' END AS ZK05_COUNT
      , CASE WHEN r.AUART = 'ZK04' THEN count(r.MATNR) ELSE '' END AS ZK04_COUNT
      , CONVERT(money, sum(CAST(netpr as MONEY)), 1) as ToplamTutar  
      FROM GARANTI_YP_RAPORU as r
      group by r.name ,r.AUART
     ) as gTablo
PIVOT
(
  SUM(ToplamTutar)

  FOR gTablo.AUART IN ([ZK05],[ZK04])
)
AS p1
```

I expect the output in single line row. How can do that ?

Comment: @jarlh SQL server 2014 management studio

Comment: It would help your question to also show us the _original_ table.  Trying to figure out what that might be based only on the current output is difficult.

Comment: Does't seem that pivot is a good choice for this. You usually use PIVOT when you want a particular column's values turned into columns, which is not this case. You can do what you need with a `GROUP BY` as Luk answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't really need a PIVOT.
Grouping them only by the Name and then using conditional aggregations should do.

```
SELECT r.name
, COUNT(CASE WHEN r.AUART = 'ZK04' THEN r.MATNR END) AS ZK04_COUNT
, COUNT(CASE WHEN r.AUART = 'ZK05' THEN r.MATNR END) AS ZK05_COUNT
, CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN r.AUART = 'ZK04' THEN r.netpr ELSE 0 END) AS MONEY) AS ZK04_PRICE
, CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN r.AUART = 'ZK05' THEN r.netpr ELSE 0 END) AS MONEY) AS ZK05_PRICE
FROM GARANTI_YP_RAPORU as r
GROUP BY r.name
ORDER BY r.name
```

Comment: Save my day ! Thanks for help.